# Git: How to keep SHAs in commit messages up-to-date after rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, sha

Let's assume that I'm on a `feature` branch, created off `master`. I do a commit

```
Fix XYZ
```

whose SHA is, let's say, `389b04`. Then, I do another commit, in whose commit message I mention the previous SHA.

```
Fix UVW

This fix is related to the fix in 389b04.
```

After that, I do a bunch of other commits. Now, I sync my `feature` branch with `master`, so I do `git rebase master`. However, as `rebase` changes history, it changes the SHA of the referenced commit `389b04`, so the second commit now references a non-existing commit.

My question is: is it somehow possible to automatically fix such SHAs in commit messages while doing `rebase`? I know this could be solved by doing `merge` instead, but I'm wondering whether there is a way of doing this with `rebase`.

Comment: I don't know of any way … if you do not have too many messages to change, you can filter the commit messages after the rebase and fix them manually

Comment: @knittl: Yes, I can. However, the manual way is rather error-prone because you may forget that you've put a SHA in some commit. Moreover, it gets tedious when doing `rebase` regularly. So, I'm looking for an automatic way.

Comment: There's definitely nothing automatic built-in to git to do this.  You could write a script you would use with `git filter-branch` to filter commit messages, but it would be kind of tricky.  In general, when I'm rebasing/rewriting unpublished history, I'll just "rebase -i" and move the fix up next to where I introduced the bug and then combine the commits, thereby avoiding the issue entirely. :-)

Comment: @torek: Thank you for the idea with `git filter-branch`. As for `squash`/`fixup`ing the commits, sometimes the commits are not really related to each other, so this may be undesirable in such cases. The example in the question is just an example.

Answer (score -3):

Rebase will invariable change commit SHA, as rebase is an act of **"history Rewrite"**

Therefore - Rebase should be done only on Un Published History.

Comment: My `feature` branch is unpublished at the time of `rebase`. I'm keeping it private, syncing it with `master` from time to time (to get the changes from `mater` to `feature`, not vice versa), and when I'm done, I will merge it into `master`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original poster's question about how to automatically rewrite commit messages during a `rebase`.